# How do I create a Ruby date object from a string?

Tags: ruby, date

How do I create a Ruby date object from the following string?

```
DD-MM-YYYY
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
Date.parse('31-12-2010')
```

Alternatively [`Date#strptime(str, format)`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).

Answer (score 42):

Because in the USA they get the dates backwards, it's important not to simply use `Date.parse()` because you'll find 9/11/2001 can be 11 September 2001 in the USA and 9 November 2001 in the rest of the world.  To be completely unambiguous use `Date::strptime(your_date_string,"%d-%m-%Y")` to correctly parse a date string of format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Try this to be sure:

```
>irb
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> testdate = '11-09-2001'
=> "11-09-2001"
>> converted = Date::strptime(testdate, "%d-%m-%Y")
=> #<Date: 4918207/2,0,2299161>
>> converted.mday
=> 11
>> converted.month
=> 9
>> converted.year
=> 2001
```

For other `strptime` formats see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html

Also I always make sure I set my base timezone to `:utc` if my website is going to be handling any dates, and use `Javascript` on the client side to display local times.

Comment: what, if any, is the difference between `.mday` and `.day`?

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Time#parse](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000305).

```
Time.parse("20-08-2010")
# => Fri Aug 20 00:00:00 +0200 2010
```

However, because Ruby could parse the date as "MM-DD-YYYY", the best way is to go with [DateTime#strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html) where you can specify the input format.

Answer (score 5):

If you have control over the format of the date in the string, then `Date.parse` works fine internationally with strings in `YYYY-MM-DD` ([ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)) format:

```
Date.parse('2019-11-20')
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this approach simpler since it avoid having to specify the date format for the parser:

> date1 = Time.local(2012, 1, 20, 12, 0, 0).to_date

Answer (score 1):

Like this You can get time Object from a string like this:

```
t = Time.parse "9:00 PM" 
 => 2013-12-24 21:00:00 +0530

t = Time.parse "12:00 AM"
 => 2013-12-24 00:00:00 +0530
```

But Ruby parsing this as a Date!

So you can use the column as a string.

```
add_column :table_name, :from, :string, :limit => 8, :default => "00:00 AM", :null => false
add_column :table_name, :to, :string, :limit => 8, :default => "00:00 AM", :null => false
```

And you can assign string object to the attribute,

```
r.from = "05:30 PM"
r.save
```

And parse the string for getting time object,

```
Time.zone.parse("02:00 PM")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary for this particular string format, but best string to time parsing utility I know is [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) which is available as a gem and works for about 99.9% of usecases for human formatted dates/times.